# Can we use the POSIX C libraries in c++?

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, posix, linux-device-driver

I am new in the field of Linux system programming.I currently program in C and want to switch to c++.

Can we use all the functions defined in POSIX C libraries in c++ without any change ?

Comment: There shouldn´t be any problems.

Comment: C++11 came with some built in multi threading capabilities you may want to look into.

Comment: In c++ we will be including various standard c++ libraries. Wouldn't there be any name clashing ? And also wouldn't there be name mangling in c++ ?

Answer (score 8):

*In principle* you should be able to use any C API from C++; the language includes features to facilitate it, and most C library authors are aware that people want to do this and will take the appropriate steps.  For the system programming interfaces specified by POSIX, C++ compatibility is an explicit design goal.

However, you may still encounter problems.  In my experience, the most common problems are:

1. C API headers often dump hundreds of symbols into the global namespace.  Some of those symbols may conflict with C++ library symbols, which will get you in trouble if you `using namespace std` (but you weren't doing that, right?)
2. C API headers often make heavy use of macros, including macro names that, yep, might conflict with C++ library symbols; `std::` won't save you there.
3. Compiling your program in a strict conformance mode (e.g. `-std=c++11 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700`) may expose bugs in system headers.  This is more likely to happen with C++ than C.
4. A small handful of the POSIX APIs have abnormal control-flow behavior that *may* interact poorly with C++ exceptions and destructors, depending on how thorough your C library implementor was about avoiding the problem.  `setjmp` and `longjmp` are obviously a concern here (has anyone done a C library that implements those *on top of* DWARF-style exception handling?) but so are `fork`, `setcontext` and friends, `pthread_cancel`, `pthread_cleanup_push`, and probably a few others I can't remember off the top of my head.  (I recall a giant, ultimately inconclusive argument between Ulrich Drepper and the GCC C++ guys back in 2004 or so about exactly how `pthread_cancel` should behave in the presence of destructors.)

If you go beyond POSIX, you may also have problems with:

1. Headers that don't bother to wrap all the declarations in an `extern "C"` block when compiled as C++, which means all the function names get mangled when they shouldn't have been, and the link fails.
2. Headers that don't even bother to stick to the intersection of C and C++.  In the worst case, this can cause failures that don't manifest until the program is run.  The most common instances of this are:

   - Blithely using some C++ keyword as a declared-name (e.g. `int template;`)
   - Assuming that `void *` is assignment compatible with other pointer types (e.g. that it is not necessary to cast the result of `malloc`)
   - Assuming that `struct foo;` does *not* define a typedef-name `foo`

Note that the *headers* specified by POSIX frequently contain system-specific extensions that have not been as carefully thought out as the POSIX interfaces themselves.

Comment: Also if there any stuff like `int class;` or `int template;` in C header -- it may not work in C++ as those are language keywords in C++ (but not in pure C). But odds are really small though.

Comment: @SamProtsenko That's what I meant by "blithely using some C++ keyword as a declared-name".

Answer (score 1):

> *"Can we use all the functions defined in POSIX C libraries in c++ without any change ?"*

Of course you can. Any c-style API can be used seamlessly in c++.

Comment: In c++ we will be including various standard c++ libraries. Wouldn't there be any name clashing ? And also wouldn't there be name mangling in c++ ?

Comment: @ShikharSrivastava Name clashing is solved using namespaces explicitely, also name mangling of c system functions is solved using `extern "C"` with their declarations. I'm often writing C++ code just wrapping those POSIX API's, it works pretty well.

Comment: Not quite. exit, longjmp and fork are ok in C, but can break RAII in C++, need to be careful with them.