# isatty what header to include

Tags: c++, c++17

All of the examples I see in manpages and online suggests `<unistd.h>`.
CLion suggested the more c++ friendly `<csignal>`.

Looking into `<csignal>` on my g++ setup, I ended up in a rabbit hole and gave up in `<c++config.h>`.

If I want a c++ friendly/c++ adopted header.  Which one should I use?

Comment: Just stick to the man pages, it's not a c++ function, just use the posix header

Comment: As you identified, there's an `isatty` function defined in the POSIX C header `unistd.h`. If that's the function you want to use, is there a reason that you can't include `unistd.h`? [C++ should have no problem interfacing with POSIX libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29952576/11082165) in most cases.

Comment: `isatty` is a Unix thing, so `"unistd.h"` is probably the right header. `<csignal>` just pulls in the contents of `<signal.h>` (and puts the non-macro names into `std`), so you get `sig_atomic_t`, `raise`, and `signal`. That's all.

Comment: Unless any of you want to answer this question. I'm going to self-answer based on the three comments above in about half an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random C headers/libraries might pose a problem interfacing with c++ code. In particular using keywords as names.

This is not the case with posix headers.

I'm using `<unistd.h>`  in all my future cases.

Comment: With regards to using C headers that use C++ keywords as identifiers, some advice can be found here: [How can I include a C header that uses a C++ keyword as an identifier in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72177535/11082165)